# Avoid downloading subfolders with WinSCP

Tags: scripting, sftp, winscp

I am using the below script

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp:-------
get -filemask=">=%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%" /outbound \\sharedrive\Copiedfiles
exit
```

Please let me know how I can copy only files, but not subfolders.

The SFTP folder `/outbound` contains csv files and other subfolders like `edi`, `test`, `debug`.

The CSV files are placed daily and these folders also get updated daily.

Please let me know how I can copy only the `.csv` files (I tried options but was not successfully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How do I transfer directory non-recursively?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_non_recursive)

So in your case, you add `|*/` to your existing file mask:

```
get -filemask=">=%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd% | */" /outbound \\sharedrive\Copiedfiles
```

Comment: Did not work Martin . Below is the error message .                                               Are you sure you want to transfer multiple files to a single file 'Copiedfiles' in a directory '\\sharedrive\'?
The files will overwrite one another.
If you actually want to transfer all files to a directory '\\sharedrive\Copiedfiles', keeping their name, make sure you terminate the path with a slash.

Comment: Yes . I dont want the subfolders to be created . Please help .

Comment: get -filemask=">=%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%" /outbound/* \\sharedrive\copyfiles     . This is the command I used .

Comment: get -filemask=">=%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%" /outbound/* \\sharedrive\copyfiles\           is giving the same result . Please help

Comment: Folders & subfolders are copied along with csv files . I want only the csv files to be copied . Please help .